# Getting Variables in and out with scipy weave

Tags: c++, python, scipy

I'm trying to use SciPy Weave to speed up a loop intensive task in a Python code I'm translating from MatLab. In MatLab I went to great lengths to vectorise it which had it running really fast. I've already tried it in Python with loops and it is unacceptably slow, so although I could probably do what I did in MatLab with NumPy and get it running just as fast I want to learn to use Weave because it will be really useful in the future. I've checked my C++ works here: http://ideone.com/E8ACaq (the variables above the first comment are the ones that I pass to weave) and I have simpler examples working in weave, but I can't get the actual code to play ball in weave!

What I need to know is what format my variables need to be in to get them in and out. Ideally I want a numpy array out and I want to pass in a variety of integers, numpy arrays and doubles as shown below (Python indents not shown because of how code works on here).

```
def GoodManLookup(CycleData,MaterialID,Materials):
nCyc=len(CycleData)
NRVals=int(Materials[MaterialID]['rvalues'])
NLevels=np.product(Materials[MaterialID]['levels'].shape)
GoodmanAmp=Materials[MaterialID]['data'][:,1]
GoodmanMean=Materials[MaterialID]['data'][:,0]
RValAngles=np.array([np.arctan2(GoodmanData[0:NRVals,1],GoodmanData[0:NRVals,0])*180/math.pi])
CycleAngles=np.arctan2(CycleData[:,0],CycleData[:,1])*180/math.pi
CycleAngles[CycleAngles==180]=179.99
CycleAngles[CycleAngles==90]=89.99
CycleAngles[CycleAngles==0]=0.01
#Get sector of each cycle
SectB=np.tile(RValAngles[0,0:NRVals-1],(nCyc,1))
SectT=np.tile(RValAngles[0,1:NRVals],(nCyc,1))
Angles=np.tile(np.array([CycleAngles]).swapaxes(1,0),(1,NRVals-1))
Sect=np.array([np.sum(np.bitwise_and(Angles>SectB,Angles<SectT)*np.tile(np.array([range(0,NRVals-1)]),(nCyc,1)),axis=1)]).swapaxes(1,0)
Amplitude=CycleData[:,0];
Mean=CycleData[:,1];
N=Materials[MaterialID]['levels'];
if CurveFit==1:
PowerLaw=True
elif CurveFit==0:
PowerLaw=False

code_cpp ="""//code on IDE one

"""

P = weave.inline(code_cpp,['Sect','Amplitude','Mean','nCyc','NLevels','PowerLaw','N','NRVals','GoodmanMean','GoodmanAmp'],compiler='gcc')
```

I'm new to Python and C++ so this is what you might call a perfect storm of incompetence!

Comment: Have you tried using `Cython`? It's somewhat similar to `Weave` in a way that it speeds your code up a lot.

Comment: Have you seen this overview of interface methods: http://wiki.scipy.org/PerformancePython